# DialogFlow get data from Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I recently created a smart home application using Actions on Google with DialogFlow and Firebase. A user can set a light on, for example, or lock a door. However, is there anyway I can add implementation in DialogFlow to get statuses? For example, if a user asks "Are my doors locked" to Assistant, it should say either yes or no based on the data in Firebase.

How would I approach this situation? Is this possible through DialogFlow? Any tutorials or guides would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using Dialogflow as the basis for your smart home application. There is a separate [set of APIs](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/) which make it easy to implement Smart Home integrations without using Dialogflow or a conversational interface.

With this Smart Home platform, you can set up a webhook and use the webhook to pull this information from Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible. What you need is a webhook. You can call the Api in webhook to get the data from Firebase.